# Installing a third party plugin for QGIS3.6 on Mac

Tags: python, plugins, qgis, pyqgis

I have downloaded a zip file containing a third party plug-in for QGIS3.6 (named AVHYAS, downloaded from https://vedas.sac.gov.in/en/download.html). The plug-in was installed via Plugins -> Manage and install plug-ins -> Install from ZIP. However, there is an error when trying to run the plug-in, because I can't seem to find how to properly install the python packages. I got the following info from the manual, but I guess it is for Windows. How can this procedure be carried out on a Mac? Thanks

[image]
[image]

### ------------------------

---